# Knowing when resque worker had completed job

Tags: ruby, redis, delayed-job, resque

I am performing some job with Resque-worker (5 workers). Now, when this job is completed/done I want to trigger another worker which processes the data previous worker stored in db. What would be the most appropriate method of doing this?

Comment: This seems to trivial for an answer, but most people I know would just put the new jobs in a separate queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is of any help, but have you had a look at the `resque-status` gem?
That way you can track a given jobs' status, to see when it is completed. But I'm affraid there are no auto-trigger functionality, to start new workers.

Comment: I can manually use library in my app and will write down trigger method. Thanks!