# Way to know that worker has finished Job/Process in Resque

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, background, redis, resque

Is there any way to know if worker has finished the particular job/process in Resque. 
Scenario: I have 5 worker doing some specific process, I want to know whether process is done to proceed with other part of code.

I am using Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.1.1 if that is of any help.

Comment: Make the worker invoke the other part of code at the end.

Comment: Also, why are you posting the same question twice with different words?

Comment: that would be fine if you are running only one worker. Here I am running multiple workers for same Job, and the other part of code deals with database that is saved by job. So that won't work here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knowing when resque worker had completed job](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383259/knowing-when-resque-worker-had-completed-job)

Answer (score 0):

you can try `gearman` if you need know this

Comment: that would be like changing whole worker code. It would be cumbersome task.

Answer (score 0):

1. log your information in your code
2. use redis-cli to check if the key of your job has value
3. resque-web and resque-status can also help you

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use something like resque-status: https://github.com/quirkey/resque-status .

If that doesn't quite meet your needs, you can always check the wiki plugin page for more possibilities: https://github.com/defunkt/resque/wiki/plugins

It is also not hard to store the fact of job completion as an extra field in your database.