# Rails: Paperclip-delay detect when job finished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, resque

hi i'm kinda noob in this ..

i'm using [paperclip-delay](https://github.com/jrgifford/delayed_paperclip) to throw the image processing in the background on resque and i'm trying to trigger action after the job finished..

i tried  forking the gem and add the action myself in it but that looks like an ugly approach ..like it appear in this question's answer
[Knowing when resque worker had completed job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383259/knowing-when-resque-worker-had-completed-job)

also thought of ripping some code from the gem and use it directly in my model

is there any other ideas

========Edited

i used

```
 if @video.save
  Delayed::Worker.new.work_off
  @video.reload
  put 'aheee'
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to videos_path, notice: 'Video uploaded and will be converted shortly '}
  end
```

like referenced in the gem README and it give me

> uninitialized constant ImagesController::Delayed

i have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the paperclip-delay gem supports this already by adding a processing column to your database.  it will be set when the processing is finished.  The info is in the README

Comment: i tried it but it gives me 
uninitialized constant ImagesController::Delayed

Comment: Right, so you arent using the gem in the write way at all.  It would be wise to read the full documentation before implementation.  Also you dont instantiate a new worker inside of your controller and kick off the job worker there, it is intended to run as a background process

Comment: it works fine in the part of uploading and processing the images
the problem is it's not seeing Delayed module

Comment: also in the example he putted it in the controller i see no problem in that

Comment: The README example isnt a controller.   He is just showing a Class code sample and then the commands you could run to do the whole process.  That is not an example of how you use it inside a rails app, as the README doesnt assume you are using Rails and ActionController at all, only ActiveRecord

Comment: well i have no clue :(